# Use the root test to determine the radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

Use the root test to determine the radius of convergence of
$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{2x^n}{1+5^n}$

How to approach it? I know what the root test is about, but that $1+5^n$ in the denominator makes me somehow confused about usage of it.

Comment: Hint : $\sum_{i=1}^\infty  \frac{2x^n}{1+5^n}\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty  \frac{2x^n}{5^n}$

Comment: So using here $\frac{2x^n}{5^n}$ instead of $\frac{2x^n}{1+5^n}$ won't change the radius of convergence result?

Comment: this is totally my bad. I somehow misread and thought you only wanted to know about the convergence. It should however be somewhat close to what you'll get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is:
$$\lim_{\color{red}n\to\infty} \left|\frac{2x^n}{1+5^n}\right|^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{1/n}\cdot |x|}{5\cdot (1+\frac1{5^n})^{1/n}}=\frac{|x|}{5}<1 \Rightarrow |x|<5 \Rightarrow R=5.$$